# Create object with R

Tags: r, object

```
 num [1:300, 1] 0.7 -1 0.6 0.9 0.5 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:300] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  ..$ : NULL
```

How can I create an object with this structure using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exact numbers you want to have, but this is a matrix with rownames.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 1)
dimnames(x) <- list(paste0("G", 1:300), NULL)

str(x)
# num [1:300, 1] -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : chr [1:300] "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
# ..$ : chr NULL
```

The `set.seed(1)` ensures you get the same result as there are random numbers involved (`rnorm(300)`)